# How do you SELECT query search "LIKE" from range data in []

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How do you `SELECT` query search `LIKE` '0451'.

Where on the sql database is [0|1|2]##[0|1|2] so the first and last number is from 0-2. 1st digit = 0-2, 2nd digit = any number 0-9, 3rd digit = any number 0-9, 4th digit = 0-2.

So value '0451' is `True` and `row count` 1. And some data may be `#[3|4|5],[3|4|5]#`or`#2[3|4|5]#`

Comment: seems like this is a string since you have have 0 as the first "digit" in a numeric type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's `LIKE` operator only has relatively limited pattern matching support.  If you need regex matching, then use `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE number REGEXP '^[0-2][0-9]{2}[0-2]$';
```

Note: That you are speaking of `0451`, with a leading zero, as an actual value implies that the column is some sort of text.  If you are rather dealing with numbers, then my answer might change a bit.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I got it working with SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE '0451' REGEXP '$sqldata';